# Http Content-Length too long - Time Out

Tags: http, tcp

I was recently going through the HTTP Desync attack presented here:
https://portswigger.net/research/http-desync-attacks-request-smuggling-reborn

This raised one question concerning the way the HTTP packets are treated through a single TCP socket. 
Usually, when we send a request over a HTTP connection with a Content-Length too long for the body, we'll get a time out. The server is waiting for more data in the TCP socket.

Let's say we send such request, we'll call it R1. The Content-Length is 12 and we have 10 characters in the body (we're missing 2 chars) 
Now, we send another request  valid request R2 in the TCP socket (HTTP connection still open).

Shouldn't the first 2 characters of R2 be read by the webserver and appended to R1? If this happened, then we would actually have a response for R1 and it would not time out. 
But that is not what happens when I perform this experience. It does not make sense to me. This is related to how an HTTP server handles a single TCP socket. How it separates the different requests, ... This should only be based on the Content-Length from what I could understand.

I'm definitely missing something.

To test the scenario I'm describing, you can use this lab: 
https://portswigger.net/web-security/request-smuggling/lab-basic-te-cl

First send this request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: your-lab-id.web-security-academy.net
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-length: 5
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

0

X
```

Here, as the the Load Balancer is looking at the TE header, the X will not be sent. However, the webserver will look at the CL header. Here, it will see 6 but will only receive 5 chars (0,/r,/n,/r,/n). Therefore, there will be a timeout (that's the detection test for this attack actually).

Now, let's do another experience.

First, send the same request than above.
Then, send this request (while the first one is hanging):

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: your-lab-id.web-security-academy.net
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-length: 4

test
```

Technically, as both of the request are gonna be sent in the same TCP socket between the Load Balancer and the webserver, we could think that the "P" of the second request will be processed as part of the first request. Thus, we could expect a response for the first request right after the second request is sent.

This is not what happens ... 
The first request times out, and then the second request gets processed and the response comes back. If we only send the second request, then the response comes immediately.

This illustrates what I was describing above. I don't understand why the "P" is the second request does not get processed as part of the first request.

Comment: Are you sure you send R2 within the same TCP connection?

Comment: Based on your description it should work. But you describe only the basic idea and not your actual implementation or way to do it, i.e. there is nothing to reproduce what you did. Therefore I assume that you simply do not exactly what you describe and that it does not work because of that.

Comment: Hi @SteffenUllrich, thank you for your reply. I edited my answer and added an experience with a lab to demonstrate what I'm describing.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen, thank you for your reply. Yes I'm sure. I just described what I do.

Comment: *"Here, it will see 6 but will only receive 5 chars"* - you have given a content-length of 5 not 6. *"we could think that the "t" of the second request will be processed as part of the first request."* - what "t" you are talking about? There are many "t" in the second request. Or do you mean the "X" which was send after the first request?

Comment: Yes, but I also added a Transfer Encoding header that will prevent the last char to be sent. I'm referring to the HTTP Desync attack (see article above). Sorry I should have said the P (of POST0) that is coming first in the TCP stream. This P should be added to the previous request as the missing character and resolve the time out